# how do you split a list into 3 lists, for each list in a list? Python Beginner

Tags: list, slice

```
list1= [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

Result should be:

```
list2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

This should work for any list divisible by 3 as well.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Result:

```
list2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried using:

```
list2 = [list1[i:i + n] for i in range(0,len(list1),n)]
```

No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
list_1 = [either Nested or not Nested]

check_list_type = any(isinstance(i, list) for i in list_1)

if check_list_type == True:
    split_list = [z[j: j + 3] for z in list_1 for j in range(0, len(z) - 2, 3)]
if check_list_type == False:
    length = int(len(list_1)/3)
    split_list = [list_1[i:i + length] for i in range(0,len(list_1),length)]

print(split_list)
```

Allows you to split any list into 3 more lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list2 = [lst[j: j + 3] for lst in list1 for j in range(0, 7, 3)]
```

A slightly more generic approach:

```
list2 = [lst[j: j + 3] for lst in list1 for j in range(0, len(lst) - 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Gotta wait two days, I'm too new.